# Continously move div with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found a fiddle that moves a div when pressing the arrow keys on your keyboard, however it needs to be pressed each time to get a fluid movement.

So how do you move a div like the example below, but by keeping the arrow key pushed down?

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/N5Ltt/2/

jQuery

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
switch (e.which) {
case 37:
    $('div').stop().animate({
        left: '-=50'
    }); //left arrow key
    break;
case 38:
    $('div').stop().animate({
        top: '-=50'
    }); //up arrow key
    break;
case 39:
    $('div').stop().animate({
        left: '+=50'
    }); //right arrow key
    break;
case 40:
    $('div').stop().animate({
        top: '+=50'
    }); //bottom arrow key
    break;
  }
});
```

HTML

```
div{
  background:#ccc;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I use Chrome. And pressing the arrow key down and holding it actually successfully brought the block down continuously.

Comment: You could do something like this (increase distance and add time) >> http://jsfiddle.net/N5Ltt/590/

Comment: Using Chrome also works for me, but the progress of movement is a lot slower than if I continuously tap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be an approach for you:

```
var pressed = false;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(!pressed){ //only start animation once
        width = $(this).width();
        height = $(this).height();
        switch (e.which) {
            case 37:
                $('div').stop().animate({
                    left: '-=' + width //allow the user the move the div over the whole doc
                }, 2000); //left arrow key
                break;
        // and so on
       }
    }
    pressed = true;
}).keyup(function(){
    $('div').stop(); // stop the current animation
    pressed = false;
});
```

perhaps you have to change the variables `width` and `height` to fit in your needs.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mgbfozrr/)**

Comment: Good one +1 i was looking for an answer

Answer (score 0):

you could set a variable to true when the key is pressed down and false when the key is let go

Comment: Welcome to SO and thx for your answer. Answers with code examples are usually more complete, consider adding code :).